# C++ - Checking if Internet time is enabled in Win10

Tags: c++, datetime, settings

How can I check through C++ code if the Internet Date and Time setting is enabled or not:

Control Panel>"Date and Time">"Set the time and date">"Internet Time">"Change settings…"

This setting:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an API to do it directly, but you could always do it via the registry Scroll down a bit [here](https://winaero.com/configure-internet-time-ntp-options-in-windows-10/) and they'll walk you through it

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the check methods via WinAPI and the registry.

We will look for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer` values (check https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/otlink-wo/How-to-Configure-a-Local-NTP-Server.html for more info).
There is one `Enabled` value that we are looking for.

So, here is a little non-optimized code with some checks (hope it works...):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

bool is_ntp_enabled(void)
{
    HKEY key;
    const auto sub_key{ TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\W32Time\\TimeProviders\\NtpServer") };
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sub_key, NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key)) {
        std::cerr << "No registry access" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    DWORD buff;
    const DWORD buff_type{ KEY_READ };
    const DWORD buff_size{ sizeof(buff) };

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegQueryValueEx(key, TEXT("Enabled"), NULL, (LPDWORD)&buff_type, (LPBYTE)&buff, (LPDWORD)&buff_size)) {
        std::cerr << "No registry value access" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (buff == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_ntp_enabled() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I need this to work without any setup or anything, like if a user uses the program on his/her personal computer. Do you think there is a way to code it with this requirement in mind?

Comment: I don't really understand the goal of your programm. Should it check time settings and if NTP is enabled then it turns it on?         Presented code (function) for check will work on any computer with Windows installed.      You can also change registry parameter (but this is can be complex; maybe change one registry parameter will not enable NTP and update clocks)  through `WinAPI` if you like. But I didn't do it before so I can only wish you good luck.. :c

Comment: This is only a part of a program. It is used to make sure that the User's time setting is correct, and he/she isn't trying to work the trial version around.